# Is there any other way of fixing this OTP verification problem?

Tags: php, html

Am making an verification system after the user signup he/she will be redirected to verify the with otp code. The code doesn't seem to work when i tried it out and displays no error to show.

```
<?php

include_once("__DIR__ . '/../connection/conn.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['password']));
    $cpass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['cpassword']));
    $role = 'user';
    $verification_status = '0';
    $otp = mt_rand(1111,9999);    //create 4 digits otp
    $activation_code = rand(time(),10000000);  //create a user unique id
 
    $select_users = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `userssystem1` WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pass'") or die('query failed');
 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($select_users) > 0){
       $message[] = 'user already exist!';
    }else{
       if($pass != $cpass){
          $message[] = 'confirm password not matched!';
       }else{
          mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `userssystem1`(username, email, password, role, otp, activation_code, verification_status) VALUES('$username', '$email' , '$cpass' , '$role', '$otp', '$activation_code' , '$verification_status')") or die('query failed to insert');
          $message[] = 'registered successfully!';
          header('location:verify.php?code='.$activation_code);
       }
    }
 
 }

?>
```

After i copy the otp from the data table into the otp input field to make the necessary changes on the data table in the database, the verification_status is supposed to change to verified and otp code will be empty from the database table. `verification_status = 'verified'

```
<?php
//if user verified, so don't show verify page

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("__DIR__ . '/../connection/conn.php");


if(isset($_POST['submit_otp'])){

  if(isset($_GET['code'])){

    $activation_code = $_GET['code'];
    $otp = $_POST['otp'];

    $sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM userssystem1 WHERE activation_code = '".$activation_code."'";
    $resultSelect = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlselect);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultSelect) > 0){
      
      $rowSelect = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSelect);

      $rowOtp = $rowSelect['otp'];


      if ($rowOtp !== $otp) {
        echo "<script>alert(Please provide correct OTP...!)</script>";

      }else{
        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE userssystem1 SET otp = '', verification_status = 'verified' WHERE otp = '".$otp."' AND activation_code = '".$activation_code."'";
        $resultUpdate = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdate);

        if ($resultUpdate){
          echo "<script>alert(Your email has been verified)</script>";
          header("Refresh:1; url=signup.php");

        }else{
          echo "<script>alert(Your email is not verify)</script>";
        }
      }
     }
  } 
else{
  header("Refresh:1; url=verify.php");
}


}



?>
```

Comment: As info, `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not effective in preventing SQL injection. You need to use prepared statements to protect against that. Also, `md5()` is notoriously weak and has been shown to have substantial collision issues as early as the mid-2000s.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code this is really just a guess, but you're checking for `$_POST['submit_otp']` but then later down assign `$otp` to the value of `$_POST['otp']`. My guess is that maybe the first `if (isset(...` is coming back false because the `$_POST` key is wrong. Or, the second assignment is wrong and the SQL comes back with no rows.

Comment: Ok, let me repost all codes for better clarification...Thank you bunch